# Gradient color animation

Tags: android, performance, animation, gradient

### What I want to achieve:

Radial gradient, who's start and end colors are changing smoothly over time from one defined color to another.

### What I have tried so far:

Using ObjectAnimator like this:

```
        searchAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drawThread, new Property<DrawThread, Float>(Float.TYPE, "fraction") {
            @Override
            public Float get(DrawThread object) {
                return object.fraction;
            }

            @Override
            public void set(DrawThread object, Float value) {
                object.setFraction(value);
            }
        }, 0, 1);
        searchAnimator.setDuration(maxSearchDuration);
        searchAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

This will call  `DrawThread.setFraction(value);` over time. Inside the thread I perform `Canvas` drawing using `SurfaceView` like this:

```
mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
radius = (int) Math.sqrt(canvas.getWidth() / 2 * canvas.getWidth() / 2 + canvas.getHeight() / 2 * canvas.getHeight() / 2);
//calculating colors for current fraction using ARGBEvaluator
int start = (int) argbEvaluator.evaluate(fraction, colors[0].start, colors[1].start);
int end = (int) argbEvaluator.evaluate(fraction, colors[0].end, colors[1].end);
//end
mPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2,
      radius, start, end, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, radius, mPaint);
```

### The problems:

1. The gradient is not smooth. Image looks like low-color
2. Performance is very low. I get aprox 16 FPS on FullHD Snapdragon 801 device.

So what I want to ask is any help in improving performance (even completely different way), and improving resulting image quality.

Comment: I would probably try using a `GradientDrawable` as a background of a normal view (not SurfaceView). And use a ValueAniamtor to compute and callback on each animation frame where u could calculate the gradient values and call `gradientDrawable.setColors(int[])`

Comment: @Budius, thanks, but I have already tried that. The performance is the same, and setColors method is not available for older APIs (like 7)

Comment: That would be my first approach as it's much simpler than SurfaceView. Isn't your background thread doing other work that is slowing ut down? Regarding API level, Not sure on your requirements but API 7 is just so old that even Google dropped support for them quite some time. It doesn't even show on the dashboard: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone

Comment: @Budius here is the API doc, which says that `setColors()` was added in API 16 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setColors(int[])    
And it is completely not an option for me to drom the support of older APIs

Answer (score 1):

You can animate color changes in gradient like this:

```
int colorFrom = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red);
int colorTo = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue);
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.setDuration(2000);

int color1 = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red);
int color2 = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green);
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{color1, color2});
gradientDrawable.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);

colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                gradientDrawable.setColors(new int[]{(int) animator.getAnimatedValue(), color2});
                viewWithGradientBg.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
            }
        }

    });

colorAnimation.start();
```

Kotlin variant:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val colorFrom = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
    val colorTo = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_dark)
    val colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo)
    colorAnimation.duration = 2000
    val color1 = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
    val color2 = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_dark)
    val gradientDrawable = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR, intArrayOf(color1, color2))
    gradientDrawable.gradientType = GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT
    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener { animator ->
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            gradientDrawable.colors = intArrayOf(animator.animatedValue as Int, color2)
            viewWithGradientBg.background = gradientDrawable
        }
    }
    gradientDrawable.gradientRadius = 140f;
    gradientDrawable.setGradientCenter(0.5f, 0.5f);
    colorAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITE
    colorAnimation.start()
}
```

Comment: You can change all colors in `gradientDrawable.setColors(...)` method.

Comment: this probably should work. I can't check it now. I used a workaround  - placed a static transparent gradient over the view, and was changing the view's solid background color

Comment: sorry, change 'RADIAL_GRADIENT' to 'LINEAR_GRADIENT'

Comment: gradientDrawable.gradientRadius = 140f;
    gradientDrawable.setGradientCenter(0.5f, 0.5f)
These variables dont seem to have any impact on the gradient at all no matter what numbers I enter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this piece of pseudo code helps  :

```
private ValueAnimator colorAnimation;

  colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), startColor, endColor); 
                                                          // you can add more colors here 

    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            yourView.setBackgroundColor((Integer) animator
                    .getAnimatedValue());
        }

    });

    colorAnimation.setDuration(maxSearchDuration);
    colorAnimation.start();
}
```

Comment: It is not a problem to animate single color on the background. But if you read my question once more, you will see that the problem is to animate a **gradient**